# How to remove "Next/Previous topic" in the Sphinx sidebar?

Tags: python-sphinx, restructuredtext

While using the basic theme, I have noticed that Sphinx (v3.2.1) seems to be generating "Next/Previous topic" sections. Is there any simple way to remove those?

[image: Example1]

[image: Example2]

Comment: Customize your theme's template files. See https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/templating.html and [search SO](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpython-sphinx%5D+customize+theme) for further help.

Answer (score 0):

Add the `html_sidebars` option to your `conf.py` file and pick the elements that you want in the sidebar. This overrides the theme's default sidebar elements. You can also add custom HTML elements to the `_templates` directory and include them in the sidebar, as well as customize what the sidebar displays on different pages. See the [Sphinx docs](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/configuration.html) for more info on the sidebar elements Sphinx provides by default.

Obviously this differs between themes since not all of them include rellinks in the sidebar, but for the out-of-the-box theme this should remove the previous/next topic links and display on the TOC and search box.

```
html_sidebars = {
    '**': ['globaltoc.html', 'searchbox.html']
}
```